# Modify "space around" width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i have trouble understanding the space around property of justify content, in flexbox, look at this little pen to illustrate :

https://codepen.io/Ziratsu/pen/gewEPO

I want two div to be on the same line but separate with some distance, what the space around gives me here is good, but if I want to add more space between these two div ? And what if I want to shrink it?

I've searched and tried to add some Id's to my divs and change the margin or padding, but it's not working.

The HTML

```
 <div class=conteneur1>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div> 
</div>
```

the CSS

```
.conteneur1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.sub{
  border-style: solid;
  background: pink;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
 }
```

I hope you get my question, I mean it's frustrating to not change the width between them as I wish to, and I hope it is possible, if not every pages on the internet will look the same with space around.

Comment: use margin to control the distance

Comment: Margin ain't working..

Comment: I want more space Between them or shrink the espace between them

Comment: i also added another way if you don't like the margin one ;)

Comment: Well I must be really tired to ask this one, IDK how I didn't make it, thank's for help, you perfectly answered my dumb question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with margin to increase/decrease the size between them

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}

.conteneur1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.sub {
  border-style: solid;
  background: pink;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class=conteneur1>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
</div>

<div class=conteneur1>
  <div class="sub" style="margin-right:30px;"></div>
  <div class="sub" style="margin-left:30px;"></div>
</div>
<div class=conteneur1>
  <div class="sub" style="margin-right:-30px;"></div>
  <div class="sub" style="margin-left:-30px;"></div>
</div>
```

Another idea is to use a hidden element between them to control the distance:

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}

.conteneur1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.conteneur1:before {
  content:"";
  width:var(--s, 100px);
}

.sub {
  border-style: solid;
  background: pink;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.sub:first-child {
  order:-1;
}
.sub:last-child {
  order:2;
}
```

```html
<div class=conteneur1>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
</div>

<div class=conteneur1 style="--s:50px;">
  <div class="sub" ></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
</div>
<div class=conteneur1 style="--s:150px;">
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
</div>
```

Or you can use two hidden elements on both sides to control the distance also:

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}

.conteneur1 {
  display: flex;
}
.conteneur1:before,.conteneur1:after {
  content:"";
  width:var(--s, 100px);
}

.sub {
  border-style: solid;
  background: pink;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.sub:first-child {
  margin-right:auto;
}
.sub:last-child {
  margin-left:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class=conteneur1>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
</div>

<div class=conteneur1 style="--s:50px;">
  <div class="sub" ></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
</div>
<div class=conteneur1 style="--s:150px;">
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
</div>
```